# Azure Redis Trigger in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-redis-cache

How can i get the data when any thing new added to azure redis cache inside azure function.Any solution available called RedisTrigger just like queue trigger or cosmosDb trigger(when any thing added to queue storage or cosmosdb automatically azure function will fire).Need help with azure redis cache update which will trigger Azure function and we can get the data.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, there's no official binding for Redis Cache you can check / ask for it in the following repo:

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/658